# How can I use custom sounds for react native local notifications?

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, node-modules, react-native-notifications

guys, I am trying to build an alarm app in React-Native where I can set custom sound for my alarm each time I set, that is sound from the device. Most of the options I found out was to use react native push notifications and alarm notifications npm libraries. They do allow using custom sounds but each time we need to dump those files in `res/raw` of the App folder. Can those `node_modules` be customised for my use case?

Answer (score 1):

you must add channelid at your project first.
I use [expo-notifications](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/notifications/) to create channelid by Notifications.setNotificationChannelAsync().
`Notifications.setNotificationChannelAsync('emails', { name: 'E-mail notifications', importance: Notifications.AndroidImportance.HIGH, sound: 'nioce.mp3', channelId: 'emails' });`[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CbkQk.png)
and then when you post notification you just add channelid in your data. (I will take a pic for example but I use firebase for post notification)[postman raw data example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fH8GO.png)

Comment: just add sound files at %projectname%/android/app/src/main/res/raw
if raw folder aren't at this directory just create it and add sounds to it.